# JavaFX Stylesheet attributes not applied in real Application

Tags: javafx, stylesheet, scenebuilder

I have made a little cool design in Scene Builder 2.0 and worked also with css attributes.
All looks great in Scene Builder but when I load the Application via:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("BasicApplication_css.fxml"));
    Scene mainScene = new Scene(root,900,600);
    stage.setTitle("VuBPS");
    stage.setScene(mainScene);
    stage.show();
}
```

The following attributes are not working:

```
#mainFrame .title{
     -fx-min-height: 40px;
     -fx-pref-height: 40px;
     -fx-padding:  0px 0px 10px 20px;
}
```

So the TitledPane is not higher than the standard one and the paddings are also not correct... why?

Comment: Please post also the fxml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this was my fault, obviously this css styles are only working with java 8 not with java 7. I switched the jdk and now all is working correctly. Hope somebody else can help this information...